# How to prove the uniqueness of linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra

$\textbf{Theorem}$

If $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space, if $\{x_1,.,.,., x_n\}$ is a basis in $V$ and if $\{\alpha_1,\cdots \alpha_n\}$ is
any set of $n$ scalars, then there is one and only one linear functional $y$ on $V$ such that
$[x_i; y] = \alpha_i$ for all $i = 1,\cdots, n$.

I have the proof but I am unable to follow it, can someone please help step by step.

Comment: You need to show existence and uniqueness; which one is unclear?

Comment: i am sorry to be rude, but please explain both as i want to cross check my thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by $[x_i;y]$ you mean the image of $x_i$ under the functional $y$. Given that, we know that any such functional must satisfy $[x_i;y] = \alpha_i$. Now choose any $x\in V$. Since $\{x_i\}$ is a basis, there are scalars $c_i$ such that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i$. Since $y$ is to be linear, we have by linearity
$$[x;y] = \left[\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i;y\right]
     = \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\left[x_i;y\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\alpha_i.$$
So $y$ must be unique if it exists, since its values are determined by its values on the $x_i$. And the above construction shows that it does exist, since the functional $y$ described above was constructed in such a way that it is linear.

Comment: i get that it will be sum of ciαi, but how do you prove that it is unique, my point being why cant there be another set of alpha i's such that the sum comes out to be same.

Comment: In the problem the way you stated it, the $\alpha_i$ are *given*, and the problem is to show that there is a unique $y$ giving *those* $\alpha_i$ on the $x_i$. Of course, if a different set of $\alpha_i$ are given, the resulting functional will be different.