# Uniqueness of a linear functional related to the space $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $(s_n)_{n\geq 0}$  be a sequence of real numbers. I read in a note that says:

> There is a unique linear functional $L:\mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $L(x^k)=s_k$, $k\geq 0$.

Why is this the case?

Here is what I thought: My memory on vector spaces in general is not strong enough, so I might make mistakes. My understanding is that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an infinite dimensional vector space (if I remember it correctly), and this consists of all (finite ?) linear combinations of $1,x,x^2,\dots$. Fix $n\geq 0$, and let $a_j \in  \mathbb{C}$ for $j=0,1,\dots, n$. Writing $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jx^j$, we get $p\in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Defining $G:\mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{C}$ by $G(p(x))=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_js_j$, the existence of $L$ is obtained. But what about the uniqueness part?

**Edit**: It seems that it's related to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896410/how-to-prove-the-uniqueness-of-linear-functional), where we write $[x,L]\equiv L(x)$. But this post is for the finite dimensional space. If $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is an finite dimensional space, then this problem is solved. If not, what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any linear map (so also $L$) is completely determined by where it sends the basis-vectors, and in this case you know where $L$ sends all of the basis-vectors $\{x^k:k\geq 0\}$.

This determinedness follows from this:
Let $n\geq 0$ and $a_j\in\mathbb{C}$ for $j=0,1,\cdots,n$, then:
$$L(\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^j)\overbrace{=}^{\text{Linearity}}\sum_{j=0}^n a_jL(x^j)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I ask you where you got this fact "any linear map is completely determined by where it sends the basis vectors" from, so that I could read more about it?

Comment: The YouTube channel 3Blue1Brown and his series, essence of linear algebra. He takes a bit of an untradional approach to this subject, but its really good.

Comment: Uh, that's gonna take time to find specific. I tried to skip some of them but couldn't find the relevant one, sorry. If it's something like this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896410/how-to-prove-the-uniqueness-of-linear-functional), then why is it applicable when we have an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with abstract linear algebra, but I'm pretty sure that even if you have an infinite basis, every vector is always a linear-combination of only finitely many of those basis-vectors. So the proof in the post you mentioned applies. An infinite linear combination doesn't really exist as far as I know (You'll need limits for that).

Comment: OK. I think I'm starting to understand better. It's well-known that $S$ forms a basis for a vector space $V$ if and only if every $v\in V$ is uniquely represented as a linear combination of those vectors from $S$. Here, it doesn't matter if $V$ is finite or infinite dimensional. Put $V:=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $S:=\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$. Then $S$ forms a basis for $V$, let's skip the proof. See next comment ....

Comment: Thus, by the fact above, for every $p(x)\in V$ there exist unique $\alpha_0,\dots, \alpha_n$ such that $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_ix^i$. Finally, let $L$ be any linear functional, so we get $L(p(x))=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_iL(x^i)$. This is exactly what you wrote in your answer. Are we done by choosing a specific $L$ satisfying that $L(x^j):=s_j$?

Comment: For the definition of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ you gave yes.